# Saving a DateTime value isn't working in production MVC3 server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

This works in my dev machine, but not on my actual production server.

I'm just trying to register a user, but the date of birth has to be formatted `dd/mm/yyyy`. For example: `28/09/1980`.

This works very well on my dev machine, I can register and it's saving the date of birth correctly.

But when running the exact same code on the product server I get the error:

```
The value '29/08/1980' is not valid for Fecha de Nacimiento (dd-mm-aaaa):.
```

What should I be looking for and what could be causing the date to be saved correctl on my dev machine, but refuse to work well on production?

If I switch the values to `09/28/1989` it works fine, but due to way dates are formatted here in Bolivia, I need to use Day then Month, then Year.

Here's the `[HttpPost]` Action method that runs when the user clicks the submit button:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserModel model)
{
    EFCityRepository cityRepo = new EFCityRepository();
    model.Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var city in cityRepo.FindAllCities())
    {
        model.Cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = city.Name, Value = city.CityId.ToString(), Selected = true });
    }

    EFGenderRepository genderRepo = new EFGenderRepository();
    model.Genders = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var gender in genderRepo.FindAllGenders())
    {
        model.Genders.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = gender.Name, Value = gender.GenderId.ToString(), Selected = true });
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Domain.User user = Mapper.Map<UserModel, Site.Domain.User>(model);
        user.UserRoleId = 1;
        user.EmailVerificationCode = SecurityHelpers.GenerateRandomToken();
        user.IsActive = true;
        user.LancesSpent = 0;
        user.GoldShopPointsSpent = 0;
        user.LanceCreditBalance = 25;
        user.GoldShopCreditBalance = 0;
        user.DateOfRegistry = DateTime.Now;
        user.LastDateLogin = DateTime.Now;

        var result = userRepo.CreateUser(user);

        if (result == UserCreationResults.Ok)
        {
            SecurityHelpers.SendVerificationEmail(user.Email, user.UserId, user.EmailVerificationCode);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Login, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            switch (result)
            {
                case UserCreationResults.UsernameExists:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "El nombre de usuario ya esta siendo utilizado.");
                    break;
                case UserCreationResults.EmailAlreadyExists:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ese correo ya esta en uso.");
                    break;
                case UserCreationResults.NicknameAlreadyExists:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "El nickname ya esta siendo utilizado.");
                    break;
                case UserCreationResults.UnknownError:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Algo durante el registro. Por favor intente de nuevo.");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

}
```

Comment: Which layer is failing? MVC or saving to the database? Have you tried 28-08-1980, as the prompt suggests?

Comment: It would help if you included the code that does the save and produces the error.  But if I had to guess, I would suggest checking the locale settings on the server - it may not be using the same locale as your dev box.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The error fires only in production, so I can't put a breakpoint there to see where it's actually firing. If I had to take a guess, I would say the error is in the ActionMetod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the culture in your web.config:

```
<globalization culture="es-BO" uiCulture="es-BO" />
```

Comment: Why would this be required in a production server, but on my dev machine it automatically reorders the datetime and saves it to the database correctly?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, because ASP.NET uses the regional settings of the machine it is executed on. So I suspect your dev machine is configured to use Bolivian regional settings in Control Panel whereas servers (especially hosted ones) normally use `en-US` regional settings for which the date format is MM/dd/yyyy. For this reason you need to explicitly explicitly speciy those settings.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Now should I place this in the WebConfig of the project level, or inside the WebConfig of the View folder?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, in the root web.config, not the one in the Views folder.